# Required package in composer.json not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, packagist

I have created using the workbench of Laravel a package and uploded it to Packagist under pica/pica-base. The package contains the following require statement:

"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.2.*",
        "gregwar/captcha": "dev-master"
    },

When I try to install my pica/pica-base package it fails stating the following error message:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - pica/pica-base dev-master requires gregwar/captcha dev-master -> no matching package found.
    - pica/pica-base dev-master requires gregwar/captcha dev-master -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for pica/pica-base dev-master -> satisfiable by pica/pica-base[dev-master].

On advice of the FAQ I also tried the procedure with 'dev'in staed of 'dev-master'with the gregwar/captcha package but with the same result.

I don't understand this because with the exact same requirement I can install the gregwar-package in any other project. And the link to the package shows up in the page of my package on Packigist (https://packagist.org/packages/pica/pica-base).

So why does this fail?

Thanks for efforts!

Comment: If I leave out the gregwar package everything gets installed perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Composer uses only stable packages when calculating your dependencies. There are two ways to override this if you want to use an unstable (dev-master) package:

1. In your root `composer.json`, require a `dev-master` version of a package (this is why you have no problem getting the `pica/pica-base` package, as it is in your root `composer.json`)
2. In your root `composer.json`, set the [`minimum-stability` flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) to `dev`:

   ```
   "require": {
       ...
   },
   "minimum-stability": "dev"
   ```

So you can basically do one of the following things:

1. Add the `gregwar/captcha` dependency in your root `composer.json` (the one of your Laravel project)
2. Add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to your root `composer.json`.

I recommend going for the second option. If you do so, you might want to also add the [`prefer-stable` flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable), in order to make sure that not *all* packages are downloaded in unstable versions:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "pica/pica-base": "dev-master"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was looking for a solution within the composer.json of my project itself. Changing the minimum stability to dev made everything work.